# I trying to print sequence but getting KeyError? in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I am getting only first input file correct output but I have A , B, C, D chain in my first file and getting right output, in this case in second input file does't have c and d chain in this case, our code is copying same data of first file data of C and D.? and also I am unable to increase this ids: chainIDs = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

I want to search A to Z chain ID, If I replace with chainIDs = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] to chainIDs = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'].

If any chain id is not present in input file then code just ignore and continue for others.

Showing error:

```
f.write(d[chainID][atomIDs[i+j]]+ '\n')  
KeyError: 'E'
```

Script:

```
import os


d = {}
atomIDs = ['C4B', 'O4B', 'C1B', 'C2B', 'C3B', 'C4B', 'O4B', 'C1B']
chainIDs = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
with open('filename.txt') as pdbline:
    for line in pdbline:
        filenames=line[:8]        
        with open(filenames) as pdbfile:
            for line in map(str.rstrip, pdbfile):                
                if line[:6] != "HETATM":
                    continue
                chainID = line[21:22]
                atomID = line[13:16].strip()
                if chainID not in chainIDs:
                    continue
                if atomID not in atomIDs:
                    continue
                try:
                    d[chainID][atomID] = line
                except KeyError:
                    d[chainID] = {atomID: line}
        n = 4
        for chainID in chainIDs:
            for i in range(len(atomIDs)-n+1):
                for j in range(n):
                    f = open(filenames+'out.pdb', 'a')
                    f.write(d[chainID][atomIDs[i+j]]+ '\n')  
                    f.close()
```

First Input File:

```
HETATM15207  C4B NAD A 501      47.266 101.038   7.214  1.00 11.48           C  
HETATM15208  O4B NAD A 501      46.466 100.713   8.371  1.00 11.48           O  
HETATM15209  C3B NAD A 501      47.659  99.689   6.567  1.00 11.48           C  
HETATM15211  C2B NAD A 501      46.447  98.835   6.988  1.00 11.48           C  
HETATM15213  C1B NAD A 501      46.221  99.300   8.426  1.00 11.48           C  
HETATM15252  C4B NAD B 501      36.455 115.053  36.671  1.00 11.25           C  
HETATM15253  O4B NAD B 501      35.930 114.469  35.492  1.00 11.25           O  
HETATM15254  C3B NAD B 501      35.307 115.837  37.367  1.00 11.25           C  
HETATM15256  C2B NAD B 501      34.172 114.876  37.039  1.00 11.25           C  
HETATM15258  C1B NAD B 501      34.524 114.613  35.551  1.00 11.25           C  
HETATM15297  C4B NAD C 501      98.229 130.106  18.332  1.00 12.28           C  
HETATM15298  O4B NAD C 501      98.083 131.545  18.199  1.00 12.28           O  
HETATM15299  C3B NAD C 501      99.346 129.675  17.343  1.00 12.28           C  
HETATM15301  C2B NAD C 501     100.220 130.922  17.375  1.00 12.28           C  
HETATM15303  C1B NAD C 501      99.125 132.008  17.317  1.00 12.28           C  
HETATM15342  C4B NAD D 501      77.335 156.939  25.788  1.00 11.99           C  
HETATM15343  O4B NAD D 501      78.705 156.544  25.901  1.00 11.99           O  
HETATM15344  C3B NAD D 501      77.106 158.059  26.824  1.00 11.99           C  
HETATM15346  C2B NAD D 501      78.536 158.632  26.878  1.00 11.99           C  
HETATM15348  C1B NAD D 501      79.351 157.345  26.900  1.00 11.99           C
```

Second Input File:

```
HETATM 2471  C4B NAD A 352      91.432  24.158  51.658  1.00 51.58           C  
HETATM 2472  O4B NAD A 352      92.697  23.519  52.005  1.00 47.28           O  
HETATM 2473  C3B NAD A 352      90.818  23.341  50.501  1.00 49.46           C  
HETATM 2475  C2B NAD A 352      91.477  22.027  50.635  1.00 48.07           C  
HETATM 2477  C1B NAD A 352      92.868  22.416  51.075  1.00 49.66           C
```

Getting Result for Second File:

```
HETATM 2471  C4B NAD A 352      91.432  24.158  51.658  1.00 51.58           C
HETATM 2472  O4B NAD A 352      92.697  23.519  52.005  1.00 47.28           O
HETATM 2477  C1B NAD A 352      92.868  22.416  51.075  1.00 49.66           C
HETATM 2475  C2B NAD A 352      91.477  22.027  50.635  1.00 48.07           C
HETATM 2472  O4B NAD A 352      92.697  23.519  52.005  1.00 47.28           O
HETATM 2477  C1B NAD A 352      92.868  22.416  51.075  1.00 49.66           C
HETATM 2475  C2B NAD A 352      91.477  22.027  50.635  1.00 48.07           C
HETATM 2473  C3B NAD A 352      90.818  23.341  50.501  1.00 49.46           C
HETATM 2477  C1B NAD A 352      92.868  22.416  51.075  1.00 49.66           C
HETATM 2475  C2B NAD A 352      91.477  22.027  50.635  1.00 48.07           C
HETATM 2473  C3B NAD A 352      90.818  23.341  50.501  1.00 49.46           C
HETATM 2471  C4B NAD A 352      91.432  24.158  51.658  1.00 51.58           C
HETATM 2475  C2B NAD A 352      91.477  22.027  50.635  1.00 48.07           C
HETATM 2473  C3B NAD A 352      90.818  23.341  50.501  1.00 49.46           C
HETATM 2471  C4B NAD A 352      91.432  24.158  51.658  1.00 51.58           C
HETATM 2472  O4B NAD A 352      92.697  23.519  52.005  1.00 47.28           O
HETATM 2473  C3B NAD A 352      90.818  23.341  50.501  1.00 49.46           C
HETATM 2471  C4B NAD A 352      91.432  24.158  51.658  1.00 51.58           C
HETATM 2472  O4B NAD A 352      92.697  23.519  52.005  1.00 47.28           O
HETATM 2477  C1B NAD A 352      92.868  22.416  51.075  1.00 49.66           C
HETATM15252  C4B NAD B 501      36.455 115.053  36.671  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15253  O4B NAD B 501      35.930 114.469  35.492  1.00 11.25           O
HETATM15258  C1B NAD B 501      34.524 114.613  35.551  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15256  C2B NAD B 501      34.172 114.876  37.039  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15253  O4B NAD B 501      35.930 114.469  35.492  1.00 11.25           O
HETATM15258  C1B NAD B 501      34.524 114.613  35.551  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15256  C2B NAD B 501      34.172 114.876  37.039  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15254  C3B NAD B 501      35.307 115.837  37.367  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15258  C1B NAD B 501      34.524 114.613  35.551  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15256  C2B NAD B 501      34.172 114.876  37.039  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15254  C3B NAD B 501      35.307 115.837  37.367  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15252  C4B NAD B 501      36.455 115.053  36.671  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15256  C2B NAD B 501      34.172 114.876  37.039  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15254  C3B NAD B 501      35.307 115.837  37.367  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15252  C4B NAD B 501      36.455 115.053  36.671  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15253  O4B NAD B 501      35.930 114.469  35.492  1.00 11.25           O
HETATM15254  C3B NAD B 501      35.307 115.837  37.367  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15252  C4B NAD B 501      36.455 115.053  36.671  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15253  O4B NAD B 501      35.930 114.469  35.492  1.00 11.25           O
HETATM15258  C1B NAD B 501      34.524 114.613  35.551  1.00 11.25           C
HETATM15297  C4B NAD C 501      98.229 130.106  18.332  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15298  O4B NAD C 501      98.083 131.545  18.199  1.00 12.28           O
HETATM15303  C1B NAD C 501      99.125 132.008  17.317  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15301  C2B NAD C 501     100.220 130.922  17.375  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15298  O4B NAD C 501      98.083 131.545  18.199  1.00 12.28           O
HETATM15303  C1B NAD C 501      99.125 132.008  17.317  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15301  C2B NAD C 501     100.220 130.922  17.375  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15299  C3B NAD C 501      99.346 129.675  17.343  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15303  C1B NAD C 501      99.125 132.008  17.317  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15301  C2B NAD C 501     100.220 130.922  17.375  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15299  C3B NAD C 501      99.346 129.675  17.343  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15297  C4B NAD C 501      98.229 130.106  18.332  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15301  C2B NAD C 501     100.220 130.922  17.375  1.00 12.28            C
HETATM15299  C3B NAD C 501      99.346 129.675  17.343  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15297  C4B NAD C 501      98.229 130.106  18.332  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15298  O4B NAD C 501      98.083 131.545  18.199  1.00 12.28           O
HETATM15299  C3B NAD C 501      99.346 129.675  17.343  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15297  C4B NAD C 501      98.229 130.106  18.332  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15298  O4B NAD C 501      98.083 131.545  18.199  1.00 12.28           O
HETATM15303  C1B NAD C 501      99.125 132.008  17.317  1.00 12.28           C
HETATM15342  C4B NAD D 501      77.335 156.939  25.788  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15343  O4B NAD D 501      78.705 156.544  25.901  1.00 11.99           O
HETATM15348  C1B NAD D 501      79.351 157.345  26.900  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15346  C2B NAD D 501      78.536 158.632  26.878  1.00 11.99            C
HETATM15343  O4B NAD D 501      78.705 156.544  25.901  1.00 11.99           O
HETATM15348  C1B NAD D 501      79.351 157.345  26.900  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15346  C2B NAD D 501      78.536 158.632  26.878  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15344  C3B NAD D 501      77.106 158.059  26.824  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15348  C1B NAD D 501      79.351 157.345  26.900  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15346  C2B NAD D 501      78.536 158.632  26.878  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15344  C3B NAD D 501      77.106 158.059  26.824  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15342  C4B NAD D 501      77.335 156.939  25.788  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15346  C2B NAD D 501      78.536 158.632  26.878  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15344  C3B NAD D 501      77.106 158.059  26.824  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15342  C4B NAD D 501      77.335 156.939  25.788  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15343  O4B NAD D 501      78.705 156.544  25.901  1.00 11.99           O
HETATM15344  C3B NAD D 501      77.106 158.059  26.824  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15342  C4B NAD D 501      77.335 156.939  25.788  1.00 11.99           C
HETATM15343  O4B NAD D 501      78.705 156.544  25.901  1.00 11.99           O
HETATM15348  C1B NAD D 501      79.351 157.345  26.900  1.00 11.99           C
```

**Expected Output: I want to print all chain ID in present input file in following sequence (Only present chain id):**

```
HETATM 2471  C4B NAD A 352      91.432  24.158  51.658  1.00 51.58           C
HETATM 2472  O4B NAD A 352      92.697  23.519  52.005  1.00 47.28           O
HETATM 2477  C1B NAD A 352      92.868  22.416  51.075  1.00 49.66           C
HETATM 2475  C2B NAD A 352      91.477  22.027  50.635  1.00 48.07           C
HETATM 2472  O4B NAD A 352      92.697  23.519  52.005  1.00 47.28           O
HETATM 2477  C1B NAD A 352      92.868  22.416  51.075  1.00 49.66           C
HETATM 2475  C2B NAD A 352      91.477  22.027  50.635  1.00 48.07           C
HETATM 2473  C3B NAD A 352      90.818  23.341  50.501  1.00 49.46           C
HETATM 2477  C1B NAD A 352      92.868  22.416  51.075  1.00 49.66           C
HETATM 2475  C2B NAD A 352      91.477  22.027  50.635  1.00 48.07           C
HETATM 2473  C3B NAD A 352      90.818  23.341  50.501  1.00 49.46           C
HETATM 2471  C4B NAD A 352      91.432  24.158  51.658  1.00 51.58           C
HETATM 2475  C2B NAD A 352      91.477  22.027  50.635  1.00 48.07           C
HETATM 2473  C3B NAD A 352      90.818  23.341  50.501  1.00 49.46           C
HETATM 2471  C4B NAD A 352      91.432  24.158  51.658  1.00 51.58           C
HETATM 2472  O4B NAD A 352      92.697  23.519  52.005  1.00 47.28           O
HETATM 2473  C3B NAD A 352      90.818  23.341  50.501  1.00 49.46           C
HETATM 2471  C4B NAD A 352      91.432  24.158  51.658  1.00 51.58           C
HETATM 2472  O4B NAD A 352      92.697  23.519  52.005  1.00 47.28           O
HETATM 2477  C1B NAD A 352      92.868  22.416  51.075  1.00 49.66           C
```

Comment: first off, don't do indexing like `line[21:22]`, this is ugly. Use either `line.split()` or the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the output loop to something like this:

```
for chainID in chainIDs:
    if chainID in d:
        for atom_id in d[chainID]:
            with open(filenames+'out.pdb', 'a') as f:
                f.write(d[chainID][atom_id] + '\n')
```

Comment: I did with replace of your code, but I am not getting expected result. Please see above expected result

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted (as evidenced by the above comment).